Commutation of the functional derivative for the 1PI effective action and off-diagonal propagators in field space
Given a scalar real Yukawa theory,
\begin{equation}
 L = \varphi_1G_0^{-1}\varphi_1 + \varphi_2 G_0^{-1} \varphi_2 - \frac{\lambda}{2}\varphi_1 \varphi_2^2\tag{1}
\end{equation}
of the two fields $\varphi_1$  and $\varphi_2$,
and assuming an external source for $\varphi_2$, which breaks the symmetry $\varphi_2 \leftrightarrow -\varphi_2$, am I correct in deducing there is nothing that forces the full connected propagator between the different fields to vanish? i.e.
\begin{equation}
G_{12}(x,y) = \langle \varphi_1(x) \varphi_2 (y) \rangle_J \neq 0\tag{2}
\end{equation}
and similarly also the 2-point vertex / 1PI two-point function
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta^2 \Gamma}{\delta \phi_1(x) \delta \phi_2(y)} \neq 0.\tag{3}
\end{equation}
Here I use the effective action
$$\Gamma [\phi] = \sup_J \left(W[J] - \int\phi J\right).\tag{4}$$
Assuming this is true my real question is whether
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi_1(x) }\frac{\delta \Gamma}{\delta \phi_2(y)} = \frac{\delta}{ \delta \phi_2(y)}\frac{\delta \Gamma}{\delta \phi_1(x)} \text{ ?}\tag{5}
\end{equation}
Deriving both terms from the Schwinger-Dyson equation for 1PI $n$-point functions,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta \Gamma [\phi]}{\delta \phi_a} = \frac{\delta S}{\delta \varphi_a}\left[ \varphi_i = G_{ij}\cdot \frac{\delta}{\delta \phi_j} + \phi_i\right]\tag{6}
\end{equation}
it does not appear so. Indeed I get
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi_1(x) }\frac{\delta \Gamma}{\delta \phi_2(y)} = \frac{\delta}{\delta \phi_1(x) }\left( G_0^{-1}\phi_2(y) + \lambda(\phi_1(y) \phi_2(y) + G_{12}(y,y))\right) = \lambda\left( \phi_2(y)\delta_{x,y} + \frac{\delta G_{12}(y,y)}{\delta \phi_1(x)}\right)\tag{7}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta}{ \delta \phi_2(y)}\frac{\delta \Gamma}{\delta \phi_1(x)} = \frac{\delta}{\delta \phi_2(y) }\left( G_0^{-1}\phi_1(x) + \frac{\lambda}{2}(\phi_2^2(x) + G_{22}(x,x))\right) = \frac{\lambda}{2}\left( 2 \phi_2(x) \delta_{x,y} + \frac{\delta G_{22}(x,x)}{\delta \phi_2(y)}\right)\tag{8}
\end{equation}
A priori I do not see any reason the two derivatives would agree.
I would appreciate any help.
Edit:
Since it was requested in a comment by Qmechanic, I give a short derivation of the SD eq. in the formulation above (unfortunately the lecture notes that I have this from are not published):
For simplicity I use Euclidean formulation so no $i$ will appear. Then using $\frac{\delta}{ \delta J_i(x_i)}\frac{1}{Z[J]} = - \frac{\phi_i(x_i)}{Z[J]}$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{Z[J]}\frac{\delta^n Z[J]}{ \delta J_n(x_n)\dots\delta J_1(x_1)} = \left(\frac{\delta}{\delta J_n(x_n)} + \phi_n(x_n)\right)\frac{1}{Z[J]}\frac{\delta^{n-1} Z[J]}{\delta J_{n-1}(x_{n-1})\dots\delta J_1(x_1) }
\end{equation}
and for a formulation in terms of $\Gamma[\phi]$,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta}{\delta J_i(x_i)} = \int_y G_{ij}(x_i,y)\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi_j(y)}
\end{equation}
is used. Hence it is possible to formulate n-point functions as the following product, by repeated application of the identity above:
\begin{equation}
\langle \varphi_1(x_1) \dots \varphi_n(x_n)\rangle = \prod_{i=1}^n\left(\int_y G_{ij}(x_i,y_i)\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi_j(y_i)} + \phi_i(x_i)\right)
\end{equation}
where it is important to notice that the dressed and connected propagator $G$ is functionally dependent on the field expectation values $\phi_i = \langle \varphi_i \rangle$, so the rhs is not just a product of field vevs.
If the action can be expressed as sums of products of fields as is usually the case it follows
\begin{equation}
J_i (x_i) = \langle \frac{\delta S}{\delta \varphi_i (x_i)}[\varphi] \rangle = \frac{\delta S}{\delta \varphi_a (x_a)} \left[ \varphi_i = G_{ij}\cdot \frac{\delta}{\delta \phi_j} + \phi_i\right]\,.
\end{equation}
I hope this helps, if not I can try to clarify it further.
Edit 2: I found a review https://doi.org/10.1016/S0370-1573(01)00010-2  which also is on https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0007355, where the different versions of the SDE are summarized in eq. (63) to (65) (the last one being the one I use).


The Schwinger-Dyson (SD) equation is e.g. derived [using Minkowski signature] in my Phys.SE answer here.

OP has via the SD equation (6) derived that (schematically up to signs)
$$\begin{align} \frac{\delta\Gamma[\phi]}{\delta\phi_1(x)}~=~&\frac{\delta S[\phi]}{\delta\phi_1(x)}+\frac{\hbar\lambda}{2} \left. W_{c,22}(x,x)\right|_{J=-\frac{\delta\Gamma[\phi]}{\delta\phi}},\cr
\frac{\delta\Gamma[\phi]}{\delta\phi_2(y)}~=~&\frac{\delta S[\phi]}{\delta\phi_2(y)}+\hbar\lambda \left. W_{c,12}(y,y)\right|_{J=-\frac{\delta\Gamma[\phi]}{\delta\phi}},\end{align} $$
cf. Fig. 1. The factor $\frac{1}{2}$ is a symmetry factor of the Feynman diagrams.
   _____         _____           _____
  |     |       |trees|        _|     |---J[\phi]
__| 1PI |  =  __|from |  +  __/ |conn.|---J[\phi]
  |     |       |EOMs |       \_|     |---J[\phi]
  |_____|       |_____|         |_____|---J[\phi]

$\uparrow$ Fig.1. A SD equation (6).

Now let's return to OP's question: Yes, functional derivatives commute. The consequence (5) [that OP has calculated in eqs. (7) & (8)] is a non-trivial SD-like eq.



Then I take it, in your opinion the equality $\frac{1}{2}\frac{\delta G_{22}(x,x)}{\delta \phi_2(y)} = \frac{\delta G_{12}(y,y)}{\delta \phi_1(x)}$ holds and is a non-trivial result of the SDE?

$\uparrow$ Yes.

Thank you very much! Also for the edits above:)
